# Get previous page name

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpftoolkit

something that I thought would be simple is turning out not to be, or I'm just not thinking hard enough :)

I have a page which I navigate to, in the OnNavigateTo event I set the SelectedIndex of a ListPicker and that works fine.

If I then touch the ListPicker and select a new value the OnNavigateTo event is fired again and the new value is overridden by the original value.

My initial thought was to simply check the parent page name and if it was the ListPicker then skip the initial setting but I can't seem to find where to get the parent page name from.

Any clues? or a better way I should be handling this?

Here's the XAML:

```
<toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="Status" Margin="10,549,163,-97" Header="Status" FullModeHeader="Status" ExpansionMode="FullScreenOnly" BorderBrush="Black" Foreground="Black" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Visibility="Visible">
    <toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
    <toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" 
            FontSize="43"                                   
            FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyLight}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
</toolkit:ListPicker>
```

And here's the Loaded event:

```
private void AddNote_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.TicketStatus.ItemsSource = ticketStatus();
    string st;

    if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("status", out st))
    {
        tStatus = st;
        TicketStatus.SelectedIndex = GetStatus(tStatus);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've never heard of ListPicker for WPF, are you doing Windows Phone development?

Comment: can you post xaml and C# code?

Comment: ListPicker is in the MS Toolkit :) i'll update with some code...

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

Ok, worked around it but creating my own page list and manually adding and removing the pages I want to check for. Bit of a hack but it works :)